# Does it matter what computer (host or client) I generate an SSH key pair on?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

If I generate an `SSH` using key pair on the host instead of the client or vice versa, does this impact if the `SSH` key pair would work or does it not matter which computer I generate the key pair on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically, it does not matter where a key pair was generated, as long as the client has access to a copy of the private key, and the server holds a copy of the public key.

It is generally *safer* to generate keypairs on the client, as then the private key never has to be copied across the network, but can remain with locked-down permissions in the one location where it is needed.